# How do I get notified of ECC errors in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, ecc

How do I get notified, when a Linux machine equipped with ECC memory recognizes a memory failure? I'm interested in both correctable and uncorrectable errors.

- if a message is written to dmesg/the syslog, this is already fine, but I'd love to know what to look for
- installing additional daemons (like smartmontools for hard drives) is acceptable
- Nagios/Icinga monitoring would be another way to go
- not all machines to be monitored have IPMI

Systems of interest have Supermicro boards (X9SCM-F), regarding an HP N54L Microserver I'm just curios, but don't care too much. All systems run Debian or Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: I didn't even know it was reported...

Comment: Running `mcelog` while monitoring the syslog seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Linux kernel supports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction#LINUX-EDAC) the error detection and correction ([EDAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction)) features of some chipsets. On a supported system with [ECC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory) the status of your memory controller is accessible via sysfs:

```
/sys/devices/system/edac/mc
```

The directory tree under that locations should correspond to your hardware, e.g.:

```
/sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0/csrow2/power
/sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0/csrow0/power
/sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0/dimm2/power
/sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0/dimm0/power
/sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc1/power
...
```

Depending on your hardware, you might have to explicitly load the right edac driver, cf.:

```
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name '*edac*'
```

The [`edac-utils` package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/edac-utils/) provides a command line frontend and a library for accessing that data, e.g.:

```
edac-util -rfull          
mc0:csrow0:mc#0memory#0:CE:0
mc0:csrow2:mc#0memory#2:CE:0
mc0:noinfo:all:UE:0
mc0:noinfo:all:CE:0
mc1:noinfo:all:UE:0
mc1:noinfo:all:CE:0
```

You can setup some kind of cron-job that periodically calls `eac-util` and feeds the results into your monitoring system, where you can then configure some notifications.

In addition to that, running [`mcelog`](https://github.com/andikleen/mcelog) is generally a good idea. Depends on the system, but uncorrectable/correctable ECC errors are likely reported as machine check exception ([MCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception)), as well. I mean, even brief periods of CPU throttling due to higher temperature are reported as MCE.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned by another poster `mcelog` is deprecated and effectively replaced by `rasdaemon`. I made a [writeup](https://www.setphaserstostun.org/posts/monitoring-ecc-memory-on-linux-with-rasdaemon/) on how to install and configure it on many Linux distributions, including instructions to properly setup DIMM labels.

Comment: The excellent writeup by @gabriele really helped me set up the `rasdaemon` when I started digging in to my ECC memory errors today. One thing I learned about my board (Supermicro  H8DM8-2) is that it would boot fine (and I could find the controller / RAS Column / Channel) with a DIMM in an "A" module. The "B" slots are used for 128 bit wide memory access and would not boot with a DIMM only in "B" (BIOS memory error). After getting data from an A slot, I then rebooted with memory in A and B slots and it was apparent what additional EDAC data was attributable to the B slot.

Answer (score 10):

`mcelog` will monitor the memory controller and [report memory error events](http://www.mcelog.org/memory.html) to syslog, and in some configurations can [offline bad memory pages](http://www.mcelog.org/badpageofflining.html). This is, of course, in addition to its usual use to monitor machine check exceptions and a variety of other hardware errors.

Most Linux distributions have a service set up to run it as a daemon, e.g. for EL 6:

```
chkconfig mcelog on
service mcelog start
```

Comment: Not supported by Ubuntu anymore. Installation gives errors.

Comment: @DimiDak https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mcelog/+bug/1752251

Comment: Yeah, thanx I've seen that, if I'm not mistaken it talks about ubuntu18 but it doesn't work on Ubuntu 14 either.

Comment: @DimiDak That's a different issue and not relevant here. You can ask a new question about it if you need help.

Comment: The guy who posted the question says "All systems run Debian or Ubuntu" and your answer doesn't work for it. So it's pretty relevant...

Comment: @DimiDak He added that after this answer was written.

Answer (score 10):

The `rasdaemon` package was created as a replacement for `edac-tools`, and newer kernels don't even support `edac-tools` or `mcelog`.

An update to the EDAC linux kernel drivers changed how the memory error counters were managed in userspace, so `edac-tools` and `mcelog` are effectively deprecated.

Comment: The `rasdaemon` [writeup](https://www.setphaserstostun.org/posts/monitoring-ecc-memory-on-linux-with-rasdaemon/) put together by @gabriele is comprehensive.

Answer (score 8):

This depends on your server hardware. A whitebox or a Supermicro system will handle this differently than a Dell, HP or IBM...

One of the value-add features of high-end servers is that there's a level of hardware/OS integration. Nicer servers will report what you're looking for as part of the management agents and/or out-of-band management solution (ILO, DRAC, IPMI).

You should use the tools native to your hardware platform.

Excerpt from an HP ProLiant servers running Linux and the HP Management agents:

```
Trap-ID=6056
ECC Memory Correctable Errors  detected.
```

*and*

```
Trap-ID=6052
Advanced ECC Memory  Engaged
```

*or a more severe*

```
Trap-ID=6029
A correctable memory log entry indicates a memory module needs to be
replaced.
```

*or the worst... Ignoring an error for 6 days until the server crashes because of bad RAM*

```
0004 Repaired       22:21  12/01/2008 22:21  12/01/2008 0001
LOG: Corrected Memory Error threshold exceeded (Slot 1, Memory Module 1)

0007 Repaired       02:58  12/07/2008 02:58  12/07/2008 0001
LOG: POST Error: 201-Memory Error Single-bit error occured during 
memory initialization, 
Board 1, DIMM 1. Bank containing DIMM(s) has been disabled.

0008 Repaired       19:31  12/08/2009 19:31  12/08/2009 0001
LOG: ASR Detected by System ROM
```

These were logged, plus SNMP traps and emails were sent.

Generically, you'll see Machine Check Exceptions in the kernel ring buffer, so you can check `dmesg` or run [mcelog](http://www.mcelog.org). In my experiences with Supermicro gear without IPMI, that didn't catch everything, and I still had RAM errors slip through the cracks and cause outages. Unfortunately, this led to [archaic RAM burn-in policies](https://serverfault.com/questions/518239/is-it-necessary-to-burn-in-ram-for-server-class-hardware) before system deployments.